# How to render Draft-js text in React from server

Tags: reactjs, draftjs

I using Draft-js to build my text-editor.
[image]

What I want to do is on clicking the submit button, the submitted text should appear on right side (as you can see, the blank side)

I'm calling a handleSubmit function to post the content to server:

```
handleSubmit = e => {

        e.preventDefault();

        const query = JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()));

        const payload = {
            query:query
        }

        axios({
            url:'http://localhost:9000/queries',
            method:'POST',
            data: payload
        })
        
    }
```

and to retrieve the content :

```
getQueries(){
        axios.get("http://localhost:9000/queries")
        .then(response => {
            const data = response.data;
            this.setState({queries:data});
        })
    }
```

I'm bit confused, on how to use `convertFromRaw` to convert the content to the desired text.

Where should I call the method ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to understand that DraftJS is a library that converts whatever you have inside the editor into it own format.

For Example, *apple* is converted to,

```js
{
    "blocks": [{
        "key": "f6b3g",
        "text": "apple",
        "type": "unstyled",
        "depth": 0,
        "inlineStyleRanges": [{
            "offset": 0,
            "length": 5,
            "style": "ITALIC"
        }],
        "entityRanges": [],
        "data": {}
    }],
    "entityMap": {}
}
```

Yep, it's that big. So, in order to convert it back from this format to *apple* you need a component which knows how to interpret it. You cannot just use a div tag. In this case, it's the editor component itself!

So you can do the following to display the content in readonly mode.

```js
<Editor readOnly={true}
  editorState={EditorState.createWithContent(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent())}/>
```

Now, say if you want to send the editor contents to an API so that you can save it in DB and then get the content from the API and display it.

1. Convert from Editor Format to JSON

```js
const requestBody = JSON.stringify(convertToRaw(this.state.editorState.getCurrentContent()))
```

2. Post JSON to your API

```js
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: requestBody
});
```

3. Get JSON from your API

```js
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET'
});
```

4. Convert from JSON to Editor format and display using Editor (You can remove readonly if you want the user to edit the contents)

```js
<Editor readOnly={true}
  editorState={EditorState.createWithContent(convertFromRaw(JSON.parse(response))}/>
```

Comment: This will only display the plain text. If I make use of bold and underlines, then it would not be updated?